# How Do I Create, Manage & Validate Sessions For Login & Profile Pages in Python With MongoDB as Database?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, session, session-cookies

**This question might be broad, but I have recently started using Python and MongoDB, and started building an application using Django. So, please guide me.**

I'm using `Django`, but since there is no official integration with MongoDB; I'm directly using PyMongo for database operations. Thus, my `models.py` file is fully empty. I'm using `Django` for HTTP page routing and for similar functions that do not need access to a database.

My application has a `/login`, and a `/profile` page. The user logs in at the `/login` page, if the credentials are valid, I want the user to be redirected to `/profile` page and display his details like Name, Email etc. I want the user's session to be stored until the cookies in the browser are cleared or set an expiry for the session.

If the user tries to access `/profile` page directly, I want to validate the session and redirect the user to the `/login` page if needed or display the details otherwise.

I don't know how the HTTP sessions and cookies work. I've read the web for information, but I haven't understood clearly. I've also gone through some Stack Overflow links below, but they exactly don't fit my need.

1. [Login to website using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316818/login-to-website-using-python)
2. [How do I start a session in a Python web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185406/how-do-i-start-a-session-in-a-python-web-application)
3. [simple implementation of sessions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773838/simple-implementation-of-sessions-in-python)

**Here is my code:**

**/login**:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        client = MongoClient('mongodb://djangouser:djangopass@1.1.1.1:27017/djangodb')
        db = client.djangodb
        newCollection = db.regdata
        loginCheck = newCollection.find_one({"email": email, "password": password})
        client.close()
        if loginCheck != None:

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            return http.HttpResponse("Invalid credentials!")
    else:     
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

**/profile:**

```
def profile(request):
    return http.HttpResponse("Ok!")
```

Now, what code should I write in `/login` & `/profile` blocks to validate cookies, manage sessions, and everything?

Comment: This is unfortunately too broad a question for Stack Overflow, as you have stated yourself. You might have better luck if you break it down into specific issues that you've tried to solve and have got stuck with.

Comment: Yeah, but I explained clearly what I am struggling with... Please do any help possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back then, I was a newbie. I don't know to implement a login/registration system as it works on the web.

#### Answer:

1. Use [Django Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) to manage authentication in Django.
2. Use [Django Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) to manage logged in users.